# Create generic function to ask a question and verify if answer is empty

Tags: shell, function, arguments

I am creating an shell application that do a lot of questions and I am using the `read -p "<my_question>" <myvar>` several times. The problem is that I also want to verify if answers is empty. So, I wondered to create a generic function to ask and verify if it is empty or not. If so, call the function itself recursively, until user provides something.
When I 'fixed' the variable name as, lets say, 'userdatabase', the things works wonderfully well. Follows the function declaration and usage:

```
ask() {
    read -p "$1" $2

    if [[ -z $userdatabase ]]; then
        echo Empty is not allowed
        ask "$1" $2
    else
        echo $userdatabase
    fi
}

ask "Provides the user database: " userdatabase
```

Of course, I don't want put the "userdatabase" as variable name for all questions that application will make. So, I have noticed that I need a kind of "dynamic" variable.
Letting the thinks a little more dynamic, it becomes:

```
ask() {
    read -p "$1" $2

    if [[ -z $$var ]]; then
        echo Empty is not allowed
        ask "$1" $2
    else
        echo $$var
    fi
}

ask "Provides the user database: " $var
```

But when I use the utility, I receive something like SOMENUMBERvar.
Obviously I am not using the "dynamic variable" in shell in the right way.

So, how does I create a function that receives the question statement and a variable name that will be filled with the variable from `read -p` command?

Comment: Why not just return the result and then `RESULT=$( ask ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share something that I've discovered late. I've tried to add a further step in the answer validation: validate also if the path exists, and I could not adapt the Rakesh Sharma solution for this.
Finally, I found exactly what I was looking for, that is a way to deal with "dynamic variable", and the real way to do this is using the ${!var}.
Here is the final version of my function, and its usage:

```
ask_validate() {

    read -p "$1" $2

    if [ -z ${!2} ]; then
        echo Empty answer is not allowed.
        ask_validate "$1" $2
        return
    fi

    if ! [ -d ${!2} ]; then
        echo You need to provides an existing path
        ask_validate "$1" $2
        return
    fi

    echo The var name is: $2
    echo The var value is: ${!2}
}

ask_validate "Please, provides the host path: " host_path
ask_validate "Please, provides the virtual host configuration path: " virtualhost_path

echo The host path is $host_path
echo The virtual host configuration path is $virtualhost_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest possible case.  Make a function:

```
f() { read -p "Type smthng: " $1 ; }
```

Call the function, assigning variable *$p* to hold its input, then show the input
*after* the function exits:

```
f p ; echo $p
```

It prompts, I type "woof", and `echo $p` outputs the same:

```
Type smthng: woof
woof
```

One way to check the variable is to wrap that function within another:

```
g() { unset $1 ; until f "$1" && eval [ \"\$"$1"\" ] ; do echo wrong ; done ; }
```

The tricky part is that the OP wants to assign the variable name as a function parameter, for which I use an ["evil" `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses?rq=1) to parse.  Passing variable *names* as function parameters is seldom done, (or needed), but this shows one method of doing it.

Test it:

```
g p ; echo $p
```

It prompts, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it outputs an error message; then at the second prompt, I type "foo":

```
Type smthng: 
wrong
Type smthng: foo
foo
```

---

This part of the OP code won't work:

```
if [[ -z $$var ]]; then
```

The `$$` is a `bash` variable that returns the current PID:

```
 man bash | grep -A 28 "Special Parameters$"  | sed -n '1,3p;28,$p'
   Special Parameters
       The shell treats several parameters specially.  These  parameters  may  only
       be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
       $      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands
              to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Although I can fill a variable in a question, I can't access my variable inside my function, just outside. So I can't even test to see what does the user answered. I can check the variable after the ask, but something simple like put the value entered just entered, echoing the variable inside the function, still remains impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
ask() {
   # $1 ---> message to user
   # $2 ---> "VARIABLE NAME" in which read will store response

   case ${2-} in
      '' | *[!a-zA-Z0-9_]* | [0-9]* )
          echo >&2 "Oops you've selected an invalid variable name: \`$2'"
          exit 1;;
   esac

   read -p "$1" "$2"

   eval "
      case \${$2:++} in
         '' )
               echo >&2 'Empty response not allowed.'
               ask '$1' '$2';;
         * )
            echo \"\${$2}\";;
      esac
   "
}

VarName=${1-'humpty_dumpty'}
ask "Provide the user database: " "$VarName"
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, I wondered to create a generic function to ask and verify if it is empty or not.

That's probably a good idea.

> If so, call the function itself recursively, until user provides something.

This... isn't such a good idea. Just use a loop.

It may be usual in functional programming languages to use recursion in place of simple loops, but the shell isn't one, and it's probably not very smart either, so I'd find it unlikely that it could optimize tail calls. Instead you'll get increased memory use if the recursion goes deep. Might not be a problem here, since you probably don't get that many iterations, but in general, it's better to use recursion only if you need to, e.g. when walking a tree-like data structure.

Also, instead of passing the variable name as an argument to the function, you could just do the assignment in the main program:

```
ask() {
        read -p "$1: " a
        while [ -z "$a" ] ; do
                echo "Please give a value" >&2
                read -p "$1: " a
        done
        echo "$a"
}

var=$(ask "please enter some value")    
echo "you gave $var"
```

Of course, we now have to redirect the reminder to stderr, because stdout is assigned to the variable. That's what `read` does with the prompt, too. 
This also works in, say, `dash`, which doesn't seem to support the `${!x}` indirect reference.